# Can I use a Lync api in my asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, status, lync-2010

hi can I get the lync contacts and them status in a listview with C#? I want to get all users from ad to a listview in asp.net web application and control wheater a user is online or offline.

Comment: have you tried any thing...have you gone thorugh the lync api MSDN , and other blogs available...first do some R&D and do some coding then come again

Comment: What research have you done so far? Did you try anything?

Comment: i search how i can do this but i don't find anythink that can help me

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Check the following links to integrate lync in asp.net applications:

> Lync integration:

http://sharpsplash.wordpress.com/2012/08/03/integrate-microsoft-lync-into-a-asp-net-web-application/

> Show MS Lync presence status:

http://htmlpresencecontrols.codeplex.com/

Comment: This should be a comment, because it will be useless when the links go dead.

Answer (score 0):

If Carlos' links do go dead, here is the TL;DR. This Javascript taps into the NAME.dll in C:\Program Files\MicrosoftOffice\Office14:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    //hide the ooui if the user scrolls.
    (window).scroll(function() {
      HideOOUI();
    });

    $('#lyncspan').hover(function() {
        //show ooui on mouseover event
        ShowOOUI();

    }, function() {
        //hide ooui on mouseout event
        HideOOUI();

    });
  });

  var sipUri = "your.contact@your.domain.com";
  var nameCtrl = new ActiveXObject('Name.NameCtrl.1');

  if (nameCtrl.PresenceEnabled)
  {
    nameCtrl.OnStatusChange = onStatusChange;
    nameCtrl.GetStatus(sipUri, "lyncspan");
  }

  function onStatusChange(name, status, id)
  {
    //In a real world application you would display
    //a status icon instead of an alert
    alert(name + ", " + status + ", " + id);
  }

  function ShowOOUI()
  {
    nameCtrl.ShowOOUI(sipUri, 0, 15, 15);
  }

  function HideOOUI()
  {
    nameCtrl.HideOOUI();
  }

</script>
<span id="lyncspan" style="border-style: solid">Your Contact<span>
```